# Converting code from Matlab to R: ./ operator

Tags: r, matlab

I am converting Matlab code into R. In one case, there is a statement involving matrix `sigma`. How can I translate that Matlab line into R syntax?

```
diag(1./sigma)
```

I know it gets the diagonal, but don't know what the `1./` is. My vague guess would be `1/sigma`. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you going from MATLAB or to MATLAB? In Matlab it is the sometimes optional [element-wise division](http://www.glue.umd.edu/afs/glue.umd.edu/system/info/olh/Numerical/Matlab_Matrix_Manipulation_Software/Matrix_Vector_Operations/elementwise) operator, so within the context of R should be optional.

Comment: Or if this is really R code, then the `.` is just a decimal point.  Why don't you try out an example and see what happens??

Comment: I am converting matlab code to R. I am not a Matlab user.

Answer (score 2):

- 1/Sigma is the invert of the matrix Sigma
- 1./Sigma is a matrix formed by the invert of Sigma elements

Answer (score 2):

In matlab, `.*` and `./` are used to do element by element operations instead of cross multiplication. 
So in this case, you should just use `1/sigma`and make sure your R matrix after conversion iis one divided by each element in the original matrix.